# flexbox create align center inner item failed

Tags: css, flexbox

How to use flexbox to create below's image?

[image]

```
<div class="add-album">
  <div class="inner">
    <span class='icon'>+</span>
    <span>Create Album</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

tried but failed https://jsfiddle.net/heLqx3vk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flexbox will automatically put the content inside your wrapper in a row so you need to add flex-direction:column

```css
.add-album {
  background: #eee;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.inner {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.icon {
  font-size: 25px;
  display: block;
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="add-album">
  <div class="inner">
    <span class='icon'>+</span>
    <span>Create Album</span>
    
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks it seems like I just missed one thing which is the flex column.

Answer (score 1):

The `display: flex` must be in the parent tag, so the items inside are organized

And also, add `flex-direction: column` in `inner` class, so the it always let `inner` childrens in each row

**CSS**

```
.add-album {
  background: #eee;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.icon {
  font-size: 25px;
  display: block;
  color: #999;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `flex-direction:column` in the `.inner` class.

By default the `flex-direction` value of flex-items is `row`, so you have to change it

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhuwanb9/heLqx3vk/1/)**

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.add-album {
  background: #eee;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.inner {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction:column;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.icon {
  font-size: 25px;
  display: block;
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="add-album">
  <div class="inner">
    <span class='icon'>+</span>
    <span>Create Album</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I am adding this propery flex-flow: column wrap;

```
.add-album {
  background: #eee;
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.inner {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
}

.icon {
  font-size: 25px;
  display: block;
  color: #999;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="add-album">
  <div class="inner">
    <span class='icon'>+</span>
    <span>Create Album</span>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```